# Dask distributed: allow client (local) cores to be used by the scheduler

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

A local computer (client) has some resources that would be useful in computation, but if the distributed cluster is used, then the client will be idle during `client.gather`. How can I create a worker on a local machine that will connect to the existing distributed scheduler?

I remember reading an issue about this on GitHub, but I can't find it anymore (the thread was in the context of using GPU on the client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the answer in the wrong repos, the correct repo is `dask_jobqueue` and this is the link: https://github.com/dask/dask-jobqueue/issues/471

In that thread, @stuarteberg suggests a workaround: copy the local worker specs by temporarily opening a local cluster, add the new worker specs to the distributed cluster specifications (one of dask jobqueues clusters) and scale the number of workers appropriately, which will lead to creation of a local worker.